# Would an infinite loop inside loop() perform faster?

Tags: programming, avr-gcc, performance

When you're writing a typical sketch, you usually rely on `loop()` being called repeatedly for as long as the Arduino is running. Moving in and out of the `loop()` function must introduce a small overhead though.

To avoid that, you could presumably create your own infinite loop, like this:

```
void loop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Is that a viable way to improve performance? Will it cause other problems if `loop()` never returns?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The part of the code on an ATmega core that does setup() and loop() is at follows:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int main(void)
{
        init();

#if defined(USBCON)
        USBDevice.attach();
#endif

        setup();

        for (;;) {
                loop();
                if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Pretty simple, but there is the overhead of the serialEventRun(); in there.

Let's compare two simple sketches:

```
void setup()
{

}

volatile uint8_t x;

void loop()
{

    x = 1;

}
```

and

```
void setup()
{

}

volatile uint8_t x;

void loop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

The x and volatile is just to ensure it isn't optimised out.

In the ASM produced, you get different results:
[image: Comparison of two]

You can see the while(true) just performs a rjmp (relative jump) back a few instructions, whereas loop() performs a subtraction, comparison and call. This is 4 instructions vs 1 instruction.

To generate ASM as above, you need to use a tool called avr-objdump. This is included with avr-gcc. Location varies depending on OS so it is easiest to search for it by name.

avr-objdump can operate on .hex files, but these are missing the original source and comments. If you have just built code, you will have a .elf file that does contain this data. Again, the location of these files varies by OS - the easiest way to locate them is to turn on verbose compilation in preferences and see where the output files are being stored.

Run the command as follows:

> avr-objdump -S output.elf > asm.txt

And examine the output in a text editor.

Comment: OK, but isn't there a reason for calling serialEventRun() function? What is it for?

Comment: It's part of the functionality used by HardwareSerial, not sure why it isn't taken out when Serial isn't needed.

Comment: Would be helpful to briefly explain how you generated the ASM output so people can check themselves.

Comment: @Cybergibbons it is never taken out because it is part of standard `main.c` used by Arduino IDE. However it does not mean that HardwareSerial library is included to your sketch; actually it is not included if you don't use it (that's why there is `if (serialEventRun)` in `main()` function. If you don't use HardwareSerial library then `serialEventRun` will be null, hence no call.

Comment: However HardwareSerial library gets probably included (can someone confirm that?) if you use some arduino functions like `Serial.print()`. In this situation, what can happen if your `loop()` loops forever and thus never calls `serialEventRun()`? I'm afraid Serial may not work in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it is part of the main.c as quoted, but I would expect it to be optimised out if not required hence I think aspects of Serial are always included. I frequently write code that will never return from loop() and don't notice issues with Serial.

Comment: @Cybergibbons, `serialEventRun()` calls `serialEvent()` for the various serial ports. By default, all of these are [empty procedures](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp), but they can be [overridden by the user](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent) to do something useful if desired. If you're not overriding it, there's no need to call it.

Answer (score 6):

[Cybergibbons's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/337/would-an-infinite-loop-inside-loop-perform-faster#339) describes quite nicely the assembly code generation and the differences amongst the two techniques. This is intended to be a complementary answer looking at the issue in terms of *practical* differences, i.e. how much of a difference either approach will make in terms of *execution time*.

---

### Code Variations

I did an [analysis](http://github.com/AsheeshR/Arduino-Loop-Analysis) involving the following variations:

- Basic `void loop()` (which gets inlined on compilation)
- Un-inlined `void loop()` (using `__attribute__ ((noinline))`)
- Loop with `while(1)` (which gets optimized)
- Loop with un-optimized `while(1)` (by adding `__asm__ __volatile__("");`. This is a `nop` instruction that prevents optimization of the loop without resulting in additional overheads of a `volatile` variable)
- An un-inlined `void loop()` with optimized `while(1)`
- An un-inlined `void loop()` with un-optimized `while(1)`

The sketches can be found [here](http://github.com/AsheeshR/Arduino-Loop-Analysis/tree/master/Code/Sketches).

### Experiment

I ran each of these sketches for 30 seconds, thereby accumulating [300 data points each](http://github.com/AsheeshR/Arduino-Loop-Analysis/tree/master/Data). There was a 100 millisecond `delay` call in each loop (without which [bad things happen](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/12300/18583)).

### Results

I then calculated the mean execution times of each loop, subtracted 100 milliseconds from each and then plotted the results.

[http://raw2.github.com/AsheeshR/Arduino-Loop-Analysis/master/Figures/timeplot.png](http://github.com/AsheeshR/Arduino-Loop-Analysis/blob/master/Data/Munged/runtime.csv)

## Conclusion

- An un-optimised `while(1)` loop within `void loop` is faster than a compiler optimised  `void loop`.
- The time difference between the un-optimized code and default Arduino  optimized code is insignificant *practically*. You will be better off compiling manually using `avr-gcc` and using your own optimisation flags rather than depending on the Arduino IDE to help you with it (if you need microsecond optimisations).

---

<sub>**NOTE:** The actual time values are not of significance here, the difference between them is. The ~90 microseconds of execution time includes a call to `Serial.println`, `micros` and `delay`.</sub>

<sub>**NOTE2:** This was done using the Arduino IDE and the default compiler flags that it supplies.</sub>

<sub>**NOTE3:** Analysis (plot and calculations) was done using R.</sub>

Comment: Good work. Graph has milliseconds not microseconds but not a huge issue.

Comment: @Cybergibbons Thats quite unlikely since all measurements are in microseconds and I havent changed scales' anywhere :)